# Persistent store capacity of JMS/ActiveMQ sufficient for 200 GB?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, persistent-storage

We are working on some application where updates to the database have to be propagated to some other application which sends changes to other systems if they are interested in them. Initial plan was to store those change notifications in a relational database table for buffering between producer and consumer. The buffer table should be able to buffer the change notifications of a week (consumer down for a week). This would amount to 200 GB (yes, GB and not MB). That is a large number, but we have a lot of data ...

Now someone suggested to use JMS for buffering instead of a relational database table as the buffer is conceptually a queue. The question is now whether a JMS system (we use ActiveMQ) can buffer that much data (e.g. those 200 GB) without decreasing in performance. We simply don't have the experience to know. Anybody out there has a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like the kind of question that probably can't be answered by anyone other than you, unfortunately.  There's so much variability in terms of hardware, network infrastructure, even your definition of how much "decreasing in performance" is tolerable, that anyone else's experience is probably not directly applicable.

Since it sounds like you've already got an ActiveMQ instance, I'd suggest you just create a new queue and start throwing data into it (in your dev/test environment, of course) and just see what happens.  The effort to do this experiment yourself is low (a few broker config settings to increase your broker's limits plus some code to publish messages to the broker), and it's more likely to give you an answer you can trust than someone else's experience from doing something similar with different hardware, network, ActiveMQ load, etc.

Comment: I'd add that you may want to plan on what to do during an outtage during this time. Recovering 200GB can take time, especially if the journals are corrupted/missing and the index has to rebuild.  Your broker could take a good deal of time to come back up (possibly more than an hour).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I should not have mentioned performance, I guess. I only wonder whether ActiveMQ could cope with 200 GB at all. But there seems no way round like starting an experiment to figure this out as suggested. Thanks for the input.